# Query works when function is not used

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a query that get's the total number of customers within a certain distance of each one of our stores using the `Haversine Formula`.

This formula is fairly big and looks ugly when I use it in a query, so I decided to create a function out of it so that my queries would look cleaner.

The issue is that when I run the query using the function, I get this error: `Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`.

As soon as I use the actual formula instead of the function in my query it runs as expected.  Anyone know why this is happening?  Is this a time out issue because the query is taking to long to run?

Here is my user created Haversine function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`MYADMIN`@`%` FUNCTION `Haversine`(lat1 DECIMAL(15,10), lng1 DECIMAL(15,10), lat2 DECIMAL(15,10), lng2 DECIMAL(15,10)) RETURNS decimal(11,2)
BEGIN

RETURN (3959 * acos( cos( radians(lat1) ) * cos( radians( lat2 ) ) * cos( radians( lng2 ) - radians(lng1) ) + sin( radians(lat1) ) * sin(radians(lat2)) ));
END
```

This query causes the lost connection error:

```
SELECT s.StoreID
     , count(c.PBID) as customers
     , sum(c.Status = 'null') as 'Not Active'
     , sum(c.Status = 'Left Message') as 'Left Message'  
  from console.Stores s 
 cross
  join console.Customers c 
 where console.Haversine(s.Latitude,s.Longitude,c.Lat,c.Lng) <= 5 
   and c.DNC = '0' 
   and c.Status != 'Do Not Call' 
 group 
    by s.StoreID;
```

This is the same query without the function which runs as expected:

```
SELECT s.StoreID, count(c.PBID) as customers, sum(c.Status = 'null') as 'Not Active', sum(c.Status = 'Left Message') as 'Left Message' from console.Stores s cross join console.Customers c where (3959 * acos( cos( radians(s.Latitude) ) * cos( radians( c.Lat ) ) * cos( radians( c.Lng ) - radians(s.Longitude) ) + sin( radians(s.Latitude) ) * sin(radians(c.Lat)) ) ) <= 5 and c.DNC = '0' and c.Status != 'Do Not Call' group by s.StoreID;
```

Comment: Either you are missing a where clause or have incorrectly transcribed

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry I missed the where clause when I was typing this up.  I have edited the post to make that change.

Comment: Most probably something as to do with the data as the query is running long enough to time out.